# why is save-buffer asking for a chmod?

Tags: debugging, saving, xemacs, script, permissions

All of sudden, XEmacs 21.4.22 starts asking whether it should `chmod a+x $f` everytime I try to save a buffer that is in Shell-script mode.

- Switching it to `fundamental-mode` stops that behaviour.
- enabling `shell-script-mode` again doesn't make the question asked again
- I spot 'AScmd' mentioned on the buffer flags area.

As far as I know, "AScmd" stands for "After Save command". I guess I accidentally enabled it.

My questions:

[x] what is triggering that question ? -- likely an After Save command

- what enabled that ?
- how can I get rid of it ?

Comment: Provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from Emacs with no init file. (In GNU Emacs that would be `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Looking at https://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/21.5/html/xemacs_6.html, XEmacs doesn't support `-Q`, but `-q --no-site-file` should be equivalent.

Comment: You can hit C-h m to see which mode AScmd indicates. If that does not answer the question, you can toggle debug on quit, then reproduce the prompt and hit C-g while in the prompt. It will give a backtrace that you can inspect, to see where the question came from.

Comment: @YoungFrog: interesting, but unfortunately I don't see AScmd mentioned anywhere here.

Comment: @Drew, the problem doesn't appear when I just call `xemacs --no-site-file <filename>` and then enable `font-lock-mode`. But it doesn't occur either with my initialization code with just setting font-lock-mode.

Comment: What about the toggle debug on quit trick? Post the backtrace if you can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- `M-: (setq debug-on-quit t) RET`
- reproduce the problem
- when asked whether to perform the chmod, hit <kbd>C-g</kbd>
- hopefully this will give you a backtrace showing which code is doing that.  If you don't know what to do with that backtrace, you can post it here.
- upgrade: XEmacs-21.4.22 was released in Jan 2009, you deserve better

Comment: That's interesting, but unfortunately, didn't helped at investigating the problem while it was there. The problem hasn't re-appeared since then.